# How to setup a PHP array?

Tags: php

Basically, I'm trying to create an array, and send the array data to my email.

I'm still learning PHP, and am confused about how to set everything up properly.

If you have any advice that can get me started, I'd really appreciate it.

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to          = "test@mywebsite.com";
    $subject     = "New Order";
    $name_field  = $_POST['name'];
    $phone_field = $_POST['phone'];


    foreach ($food as $key => $item) {
        $body.= $key." - ".$item ["how_many"]
    }


    $food = array(
    'mexican_torta' => array('how_many' => 2, 'customize' => NO),
    'fish_sandwich' => array('how_many' => 0, 'customize' => 0)
    )
    );

    echo $food['mexican_torta']['how_many'];
}

$body = "Name: $name_field\nPhone: $phone_field\nKey: $key\nItem $item"

echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class ="item">
    <img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/mexicantortas.jpg">
    <h1>Mexican Torta - $8.50</h1>
    <h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
    <input type='text' name='food[mexican_torta][how_many]'>
    <h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
    <input type='text' name='food[mexican_torta][customize]'>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->

<div class ="item">
    <img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/fishsandwich.jpg">
    <h1>Fish Sandwich - $8.50</h1>
    <h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
    <input type='text' name='food[fish_sandwich][how_many]'>
    <h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
    <input type='text' name='food[fish_sandwich][customize]'>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `$_POST` data is empty? Do you have a `<form>` tag anywhere, or just form elements? For that matter, where are the `name` and `phone` fields?

Answer (score 2):

`$food` is being defined after the loop, instead of before the loop, and has an extra trailing `)`:

```
$food = array( 
    // NO is also not defined as of yet, see Matheiu's answer.
    'mexican_torta' => array('how_many' => 2, 'customize' => NO), 
    'fish_sandwich' => array('how_many' => 0, 'customize' => 0)
);
```

Before the loop, it's a good practice to define the variables you'll be using:

```
$body = '';
foreach( $food as $key => $item) {
```

In the loop, you're missing a semicolon:

```
$body.= $key." - ".$item ["how_many"]; 
                                     ^
```

And your body statement is missing a semicolon:

```
$body = "Name: $name_field\nPhone: $phone_field\nKey: $key\nItem $item";
                                                                       ^
```

Finally, this last statement overwrites `$body`, so the loop isn't doing anything. Consider something like this:

```
$body .= "Name: $name_field\nPhone: $phone_field\nKey: $key\nItem $item";
```

Although note that `$key` and `$item` will point to the last element in the `$food` array, and `$item` is an array, so it won't properly convert to a string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to focus on your **HTML**:

```
<div class ="item">
    <img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/mexicantortas.jpg">
    <h1>Mexican Torta - $8.50</h1>
    <h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
    <input type='text' name='food[mexican_torta][how_many]'>
    <h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
    <input type='text' name='food[mexican_torta][customize]'>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->
```

This looks like you're trying to access `$food`, but aren't doing it inside PHP tags. If you want your code to be parsed as PHP, you have to tell the server that it has to parse it as PHP:

```
<div class ="item">
    <img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/mexicantortas.jpg">
    <h1>Mexican Torta - $8.50</h1>
    <h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
    <input type='text' name='<?php echo $food['mexican_torta']['how_many']; ?>'> <!-- major difference here -->
    <h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
    <input type='text' name='<?php echo $food['mexican_torta']['customize']; ?>'> <!-- major difference here -->
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->
```

Comment: I think with your answer we covered everything that is wrong in the OP's source code ;)

Comment: @MathieuImbert Even though it's the `name` attribute, which is confusing as hell. That should either be a `value` or the `name` attribute is being used *very* wrongly.

Comment: You're right it's probably `value="<?php echo $food['mexican_torta']['how_many']; ?>"`. But who knows what the `name` is supposed to be...

Comment: @MathieuImbert This question is unsalvageable. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You have a parse error while creating your array. It'S probably the reason while it's not working:

```
$food = array(
  'mexican_torta' => array('how_many' => 2, 'customize' => NO),
  'fish_sandwich' => array('how_many' => 0, 'customize' => 0)
);
```

And `NO` is not defined. You should be consistent and change it to `0`.

Comment: ...or at least use the string `'NO'`.

Comment: `NO` may be a constant defined earlier in the code.

Comment: @Jocelyn nowhere in the sample is that indicated. Don't assume.

Comment: @Jocelyn Could be. But it seems to me that there is nothing else than the provided code.

Comment: @Matt: Don't tell me not to make assumptions when you just assumed that `NO` is a string. The truth is none of us so far really know what it is, only the OP knows.

Comment: Judging on the OP, it is clear we can assume NO is defined as: `define( 'YES', 'NO'); define( 'NO', YES);`.

Comment: @Jocelyn I'm out of +1's, but I will try to remember to +1 that comment. You're absolutely correct and I was technically being a hypocrite.

Comment: @Matt I still have plenty of +1s. I'll give one to each of you. Hopefully I won't get flagged for serial upvoting.